# How to implement multiple language on MFC application

Tags: c++, mfc

I already built an application using MFC and it is in English. How can I implement multiple language for my application? Is there a simple way to do that, I mean without need a big change on my code?

Comment: What you are looking for is called [localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/mfc/tn057-localization-of-mfc-components). Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737343/vc-10-mfc-what-is-the-correct-way-to-do-localization) will help also you?

Comment: [Localized Resources in MFC Applications: Satellite DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/localized-resources-in-mfc-applications-satellite-dlls).

Comment: I use appTranslator but it is sadly no longer available commercially.

Comment: No need to use satellite Dll's (this is for large projects). I use this solution decribed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53557580/add-a-second-language-to-a-mfc-project-without-using-resource-dlls  It works for me!